# hangpara first line slightly indented

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

I'm using the `hanging` package to create paragraphs with hanging indents. From what I understand, the basic way to do this with this package is to do

```
\hangpara{15pt}{1}
Your paragraph.
The second sentence.
```

Where "15pt" is the size of the indent, and "1" is how many lines will not be indented.
However, when using this with my other normal paragraphs, the first line of my hanging paragraphs is not lining up with all the other normal paragraphs. Right now my hack of a fix is just

```
\hspace{-3pt}
```

and it looks really close, but I know its not the same and its bugging me lol. How can I use the `hanging` package and `\hangpara` to get the output I desire, with all "non-indented" lines lining up? Here is an image of my current output ("non" and "Morbi" should be lining up):

[image: hangpara output]

And here is my code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

% For hanging indents
\usepackage{hanging}

% Even though 15pt is default but just to be precise
\setlength\parindent{15pt}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer velit nibh, viverra
vitae placerat eget, porta a ipsum. Integer ullamcorper, odio vulputate molestie 
condimentum, massa tellus consectetur quam, viverra condimentum ligula nibh ut risus. 
Vivamus sit amet eros eu ligula efficitur finibus vel a mauris. Ut ut est facilisis,
mollis purus in, maximus est. Praesent ut libero nec enim vulputate scelerisque. Fusce 
congue dui dolor, at dictum ante pulvinar non. Quisque ultrices sagittis venenatis. 

\hangpara{15pt}{1}
Morbi vitae lacus quis elit tincidunt commodo. Fusce magna massa, aliquam vitae 
facilisis sit amet, feugiat non lectus. Nulla rutrum ac justo a suscipit. Duis dictum
turpis euismod velit ultricies rhoncus. Proin pellentesque id justo eu fermentum. Duis 
nmi leo, scelerisque quis augue sed, ultrices fermentum elit. Maecenas in nunc 
feugiat, euismod eros id, placerat lacus. Donec eu nunc augue. Proin volutpat quam a 
orci aliquet porta. Cras pellentesque nibh ac diam faucibus, eu suscipit augue 
aliquam. Vestibulum convallis semper fermentum. 

\end{document}
```

If there is an alternate, simple solution that does not use the `hanging` package I'm all for that as well. Thanks!

Comment: Use `\hangpara{15pt}{1}%` - note the use of `%` at the end of the line, which avoid a so-called spurious space. See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)